# jQuery validate group by class

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

According to the jQuery Validation [docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#groups), groups are defined by listing the element names, separated by space. For a list of elements that have dynamically constructed names it all gets a bit complicated.

I have generated a string by looping 50 iterations to cover the most extreme cases, but this of course feels like VERY bad programming. What I am looking for is a way of defining a group by class name. Is there a nicer workaround than my ugly hack?

Comment: Can we see some source code?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of the `groups` option and you'll need to show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP:**

> *"What I am looking for is a way of defining a group by class name. Is there a nicer workaround than my ugly hack?"*

No.

The best way to use the `groups` option is exactly defined in the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#groups).

```
$("#myform").validate({
    groups: {
        username: "fname lname"
    }
});
```

---

**Quote OP:**

> *"I have generated a string by looping 50 iterations to cover the most extreme cases, but this of course feels like VERY bad programming."*

It feels like very bad form design.  I cannot imagine a scenario where you'd need to consolidate 50 validation messages into one.

---

[The `groups` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#groups) is most typically used in conjunction with [the `require_from_group` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/).  When using `require_from_group`, you'd normally see the same message, `"Please fill at least {0} of these fields."`, repeated next to every single field in the group.  If you only want a single message to display for the entire group, you'd use the `groups` option to consolidate the messages into one.  Then you could use the `errorPlacement` option to precisely place this single message into your layout.

Assigning validation rules by `class` or group is something else entirely, and has nothing to do with the `groups` option.

With what little you've shown, it's very unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery and clever error label placement in your html you can do this using the errorPlacement function Like so:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      if ($(element).hasClass('className')) {
        $('#myErrorLabel').one('focus', function() {
          $(error).insertAfter('#someElement');
        });
      } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
      }
    }
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f3qv9vk0/

This way, you can grab groups of checkboxes or other elements by their class name. I found that using the "groups" gets very heavy with 5 or more checkboxes.